# Create an environment variable

Tags: node.js, cmd, sendgrid

I'm trying to create an environment variable using **cmd** to send an email through Node.js
and sendGrid. I'm fallowing a tutorial on SendGrid and they are asking me to run this code:

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

but the **cmd** don't recognize the **source** command.

Is there another command i can use or a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can use powershell instead of cmd, which supports the source command, but you can also use `call myenv.bat` to set all the variables in CMD.

Comment: Could you show me how to use call myenv, cause i'm totaly new to these things, and about PowerShell, I get the same error